# Implement form parts in different classes

Tags: c#, forms, controls

I have a main window with two buttons (this is a simplified description). A click on a button opens another form. Both buttons open different forms.

I'd like to move the content of the two sub forms to the main window and switch between them using a `TabControl`, but I don't want to move the complete code to the main window class.

How can I keep the code separated? One idea I had is to create two user controls, instead of the two sub forms. Are there other/better options?

Comment: This is exactly what user controls are for. There are other ways to do it, but you'd really have to know your way around wiring up events and so forth.

Comment: In WinForms designer, you can just copy/paste the controls into the main form tab control. Then copy-paste the code behind the controls. With a bit of work you have implemented the functionality of each form into a tab. But yes it will require all the code to be under the main class. If you are afraid of clutter, split it amond different files using the `partial class`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the sub-forms initially, before the user may change the values of their components, you could as well put that functionality into the `partial class` the rest of the main-form (in this example `Form1`) is in, just with yet another file. [More on partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#partial-classes)

Otherwise, you could do something like this:

```
public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    SubForm1 sub1 = new SubForm1();
    this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(sub1.button1);
    this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(sub1.button2);
    SubForm2 sub2 = new SubForm2();
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(sub2.label1);
    this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(sub2.checkBox1);
}
```

You will have to make sure every control in the sub-forms is `public`.